# Cannot transform point in OpenLayer (not able to find proj4js)

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

I am no more able to reproject a point in [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) 6:

```
let center = ol.proj.transform(
  [2600000.0, 1200000.0],
  'EPSG:2056',
  'EPSG:4326'
);
```

=>
[image]

But this is working:

```
let center = ol.proj.transform(
  [46.88668, 7.47806],
  'EPSG:4326',
  'EPSG:3857'
);
```

Adding this line doesn't work: `ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);` (as suggested in this GitHub page: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9199): [image]

Even when defining a [proj4js](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2056/proj4js/) string before, nothing changes:

```
proj4js.defs["EPSG:2056"] = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";    
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
```

Is OpenLayers not able to natively handle other standard projection than EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857?

What did I missed?

OL source that I use is from here: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js

And I proj4js from here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.0/proj4.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out:

The proj string has to be given as:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:2056","+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
```

not as:

```
proj4js.defs["EPSG:2056"] = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";    
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
```

In the latter case, `proj4js` in `undefined`. Maybe it's deprecated in favor of `proj4`(?).

An example is shown in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtyrws39/